# Making a New R DataFrame from 2 Existing Ones

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 2 data frames in R. One has 187 observations and one has 195. I need to create a new data frame consisting of only the 8 observations that are not common between the two. Data frame 1 (with 195 observations) is called merged. Data frame 2 (with 187 observations) is called merged 2013. There is a column called Country.Code in both data frames and each observation has a unique code that would separate it from the others. How can I complete this task? Please list a function and explain it if possible!

Thank you!

Comment: look at dplyr::anti_join

Answer (score 1):

Try using logical indexing.  This returns the subset of rows where the Country.Code's don't match:

```
 merged[ !(merged$Country.Code %in% merged2013$Country.Code) , ]
```

Edited the names of the dataframes to match the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand your perspective. If I `rbind` my results with `df2` (that I've renamed merged2013 in accor with the question) , then I reconstruct the contents of `df1`, just with a different ordering of rows.

Comment: Sorry, misread this when looking at another ... you're right of course. In context, rbind-ing it is rather, um, foolish (and reverses the intent). I gotta slow down these drive-by comments. I still like the ref to `big %in% small`, though :-)